# Hidden page tracks Read/Unread Inbox items better than API or Inbox?

Tags: support, discussion, api, inbox

How does **[this hidden page (stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox)](https://stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox)** know which Inbox notifications I have/haven't opened?

Both the drop-down [image: inbox] inbox and the API (ie, [`api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox)) seem to *mark **all** my messages as read as soon as I read one.*

[image: navbar]

I'd like to retrieve that data as well (for more than the 25 listed on that page).

Also just to confirm, there's no way to `Mark as Unread`, correct?

Comment: No, there is no way to mark as unread. What is seen cannot be unseen. Also, I don't think I observe this behavior.  What makes you think that all messages are being marked as read? (Other than [this ancient MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read)?)  (And maybe you can "read" an item without visiting the link?) Have you tried the `inbox/unread` route? ...  Also, you can get all of your inbox items at [stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).

Comment: if you open [topbar/navbar](https://stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox) in a separate window (assuming you have some "dark blue" items showing like the image above), then arrange the window s so you can see what happens when you go to the same notifications in your inbox, it's clear that they're being marked as "read" - even though the Inbox shows no new items.

Comment: Still not sure I see that, and it's difficult to test without a reliable stream of messages...  Maybe you could catch a video screenshot?  That background page is just showing whether your browser has navigated to that exact URL. But that's not the only way to see a comment in its native environment.

Comment: This is what i'm referring to ([iamge](https://preview.ibb.co/gEU947/notify.gif))... although I didn't notice til just now that the links in the Inbox drop-down actually *are* 2 different colors.  (No, i don't normally keep my visited links *green* that was just for testing but unfortunately doesn't apply to SO, lol)

Comment: So problem mostly solved, right?  (And it could apply to SO -- just need to make a *Stylish* style. (^_^) )